# Django 1.5 extend admin/change_form.html object tools

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-templates, django-admin

I'm new to Django but I've been really enjoying it.  But occasionally I seem to run into places where I just don't seem to get things correct.   So, I'm asking for some help and guidance.

I'm trying to extend the object-tools for one of my models so I can have a Print button next to History.

My templates is as follows:

```
project/app/templates/admin/
```

I'm *successfully* extending base_site.html with no issues.

```
project/app/templates/admin/base_site.html
```

However, when I add change_form.html like so:

```
project/app/templates/admin/change_form.html
```

With the following:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block object-tools %}
    <a href="one">One</a>
    <a href="one">Two</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I get an exception: **maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

This seems like I'm missing something quite basic.

Things that I've tried:

- Many variations of the {% block %}
- extending base_site, base etc ...
- adding /model as part of the path (project/app/templates/admin/model/change_form.html)

I'm confused and unsuccessful.

P.S.: I'm also using a bootstrap theme from here http://riccardo.forina.me/bootstrap-your-django-admin-in-3-minutes/ but for the purposes of this problem I'm currently not using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `admin/change_form.html` in your `{% extend %}` block is getting resolved as `project/app/templates/admin/change_form.html`.

One solution is to create a subdirectory of `templates` named for your app - possibly `project/templates/admin/app/change_form.html`.

> In order to override one or more of them, first create an admin directory in your project’s templates directory. This can be any of the directories you specified in TEMPLATE_DIRS.
>
> Within this admin directory, create sub-directories named after your app.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

Comment: I did this, modified my settings to look for it, and it worked correctly.  My only comment is that I end up with a template directories for project/app/templates/admin and project/templates/admin/app.  Is that normal in django projects?  It seems so messy to me.

Comment: For the admin, unless you override the views to support a different structure you have to follow the structure it's expecting - meaning there needs to be an 'admin' directory somewhere it can find it, and that your extension of 'admin/change_form.html' doesn't cause it confusion (as it did originally).  If you prefer, I think 'project/app/templates/admin/app/change_form.html' would also work.  Personally, I tend to just end up with most stuff in the projects-level templates directory, but that's partly just out of habit and a tendency towards self-contained projects.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're extending the template with itself. What I do is put my custom admin templates in `templates/admin`. Then in that same folder I symlink to the django admin folder (`templates/admin/admin`).

So my extends looks like:

```
 {% extends 'admin/admin/change_form.html' %}
```

Make sure you also override `index.html` if you want to go down that path.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this that I have found is to use `'..'` to go up a couple of directories, then go back down into directories that should only be found in the Django code base.

As the Django templates are in something like `"django/contrib/admin/templates/admin"`, I found that this worked me:

```
{% extends "../../admin/templates/admin/change_form.html" %}
```

If that still causes a clash with some other structure you have, you could go further:

```
{% extends "../../../contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html" %}
```

or even:

```
{% extends "../../../../django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html" %}
```

Although it is a little hacky, at least by doing the above you don't have to use some other technique that involves copying the django source or setting up a symlink.